# Adding sheet name to all formula references in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm working with multiple sheets and want to add the sheetname before every reference.

Ex:

```
=SUM(A1:A5, Sheet1!C3:C5, Sheet2!A1:A5)
```

to:

```
=SUM(ThisSheet!A1:A5, Sheet1!C3:C5, Sheet2!A1:A5)
```

I have many **different formulas** in both structure and reference so it has to be something that works with multiple variations, maybe using regular expressions.

Comment: Provide a block of code for more clarity.

Comment: Does Find & Replace not work? I feel Find:`=SUM(A1:A5,` & Replace:`=SUM(ThisSheet!A1:A5,` shouldnt cause any issue

Comment: @Mr.Burns This will work if you know the addresses. I guess he is looking for a generic solution that works for all addresses. But that means you need to parse **all** kind of formulas and find the addresses. That also means that you need to distinguish between real addresses and eg. strings that look like addresses. While `=Sum(A1:A5)` is a address, `=Left("A1:A5", 2)` is NOT an address but just a string but `=Indirect("A1:A5")` is an address (NOT only a string). So this task will be incredible difficult: Level Expert.

Comment: While a solution using regular expressions can be attempted and manually fix any formulas that were wrongly replaced, I think it's too big of a mess to try and I can't think of any other automatic solution.

Comment: @Mr.Burns It isn't a find and replace issue, as I said in the answer the formulas are all different in reference and structure

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you, I would think this had a simple solution and that other people had wondered the same before but maybe this is why I couldn't find any answers

Comment: @eduardo0 see the answer below, not perfect but it might cover the most of the different structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses a regular expression pattern to find the ranges in each formula so that the sheets' names can be added before them if needed. It's possible that there's still some edge cases where this doesn't work as expected but currently it does work in every case that has been thought of and tested.

Add a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions and use the code below:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim CellsWithFormulas As Range
Dim CellWithFormula As Range
Dim RegEx As New RegExp
Dim Formula As String

RegEx.Global = True
RegEx.Pattern = "([^!"":A-Z$])((?:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?:\:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?)|(?:\$?[A-Z]+\:\$?[A-Z]+?)|(?:\$?\d+\:\$?\d+?))(?!([^\\\/*?:\[\],;]*\!|\())"
For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
  On Error Resume Next
  Set CellsWithFormulas = Ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers + xlTextValues + xlLogical + xlErrors)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not CellsWithFormulas Is Nothing Then
    For Each CellWithFormula In CellsWithFormulas
      Formula = CellWithFormula.Formula
      Formula = RegEx.Replace(Formula, "$1'" & Ws.Name & "'!$2")
      CellWithFormula.Formula = Formula
    Next CellWithFormula
    Set CellsWithFormulas = Nothing
  End If
Next Ws
```

Comment: It doesn't even cover the in the example provided formula correctly.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I updated it and it should cover it now. The cases where a formula has strings are a little more complicated but that's the basic start for simple formulas.

Comment: No it doesn't cover it. It will work for the first address `A1:A5` but mess up the other 2 addresses that already have a sheet specified `Sheet1!C3:C5` or it will ignore any of the further addresses if they don't have a sheet specified: https://regex101.com/r/DgLojg/1

Comment: Have a look at [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/KHl5vw/3) which gets much closer to what you tried (but still not perfect). At least it covers the most common address types like column and row addresses eg. `A:F` and `1:5` as well as formulas with fixed addresses containing `$` like `$A$1:$A$5` as well as mixed addresses `$A1:A$5`. It ignores addresses in quotes `""` and addresses that already have a sheet name. • It does not cover addresses in the R1C1 notation.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks. I edited again with that pattern though it takes me a while to try understanding it completely. One case where I think it does fails is when the sheet name matches as if it was a cell address (e.g. sheet "SHEET1").

Comment: As I said, still much space for improvement :) This was just a quick and dirty 3 minutes solution. For a good one some good sample data and deeper investigation is needed. I just used your's as template and modified it a bit. The `|` are OR operators. So it means `(?:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?:\:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?)` like `A1:A5` or `(?:\$?[A-Z]+\:\$?[A-Z]+?)` like `C:F` or `(?:\$?\d+\:\$?\d+?)` like `1:6` all with a possible `$`. So it is basically just a little improvement of your original.

Comment: To exclude the sheet names looking like an address like `SHEET1` append `(?![^\\\/*?:\[\],;]*\!)` to the current pattern. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/KHl5vw/5).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Nice :) I also found that the same can happen with Excel functions that look like cells (e.g. function `ATAN2(x, y)`) or UDFs (user defined functions). Checking ahead for `(` should do it I think.

Comment: sorry that was too quick, that messed up something else

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Ok. Just so you're aware (in case it is important) in some languages the functions' parameters' seperators are `;` instead of `,` (and decimal separation `.` is `,` for that matter).

Comment: Yes I'm on a german Excel where it is `;` so I'm aware of it. Check out [`([^!":A-Z$])((?:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+(?:\:\$?[A-Z]+\$?\d+)?)|(?:\$?[A-Z]+\:\$?[A-Z]+?)|(?:\$?\d+\:\$?\d+?))(?!([^\\\/*?:\[\],;]*\!|\())`](https://regex101.com/r/KHl5vw/7) should cover the function names as well.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I'm on spanish excel so we also use `;` inside functions. I'm not sure why but your regex has a lineskip if I do  `=SUM(A1:A5; Sheet1!C3:C5; Sheet2!A1:A5;B5:C10)`

Comment: @eduardo0 can you explain? I get `=SUM('THISSHEET'!A1:A5; Sheet1!C3:C5; Sheet2!A1:A5;'THISSHEET'!B5:C10)` form this line which should be good? What do you mean by line skip?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ my bad, it was correct I was just looking at it on a streched screen. Thanks then I'll consider this solved :)